# Connection Closing error

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

i have two DataReader in this code and vs give me this error "The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open." the errors come from connection2 . i look at my code but my two connection was closed . where is the problem?

```
     protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    using (SqlConnection connection1 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {
        string strquery1 = " with distinctvalueyes (typearticle) as (select top 1 'Fruit' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Fruit=1  union all select top 1 'Drink' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Drink=1 union all select top 1 'Desert' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Desert=1  union all select top 1 'MainFood' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where MainFood=1 union all select top 1 'Salad' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Salad=1 union all select top 1 'TableFlower' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where TableFlower=1 union all  select top 1 'SaloonLighting' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SaloonLighting=1 union all  select top 1 'Saloondesign' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Saloondesign=1 union all select top 1 'SloonCrew' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where SloonCrew=1  union all  select top 1 'Pastry' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where Pastry=1 union all  select top 1 'GiftCard' FROM WeedingSalonGeneralRes where GiftCard=1 )  select * from distinctvalueyes ";
        connection1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = connection1;
        cmd1.CommandText = strquery1;
        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        lbl2_customerid.Text = cis;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            lbl8_fruit.Text = reader[0].ToString();

            // wrapped in a using block, connection will now always be closed and disposed
            using (SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection())
            {
                //query for fetch service prices 
                string strquery2 = "SELECT Fruit_price,Drink_price,Desert_price,MainFood_price,Salad_price,TableFlower_price,SaloonLighting_price,SaloonDesign_price,SaloonCrew_price,Pastry_price,GiftCard_price  FROM GenReservationServicePrice";
                connection2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = connection2;
                cmd2.CommandText = strquery2;
                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader2.Read())
                {
                    string Fruit_price;
                    string Drink_price;
                    string Desert_price;
                    string MainFood_price;
                    string Salad_price;
                    string TableFlower_price;
                    string SaloonLighting_price;
                    string SaloonDesign_price;
                    string SaloonCrew_price;
                    string Pastry_price;
                    string GiftCard_price;


                    Fruit_price = reader[0].ToString();
                    Drink_price = reader[1].ToString();
                    Desert_price = reader[2].ToString();
                    MainFood_price = reader[3].ToString();
                    Salad_price = reader[4].ToString();
                    TableFlower_price = reader[5].ToString();
                    SaloonLighting_price = reader[6].ToString();
                    SaloonDesign_price = reader[7].ToString();
                    SaloonCrew_price = reader[8].ToString();
                    Pastry_price = reader[9].ToString();
                    GiftCard_price = reader[10].ToString();


                    lbl8_fruit.Text = Fruit_price;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}



///connection class 
public class DBConnection
{
 private static SqlConnection connection=null;
 public DBConnection()
{

}

public static SqlConnection getConnection()
{
    if (connection != null)
    { return connection; }
    else
    {
        String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        return connection;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: take connection2.Close(); outside the if statement.

Comment: i move the connection2.Close(); outside the if statement but again i have that error

Comment: Try enclosing the second block starting from connection2.Open(); in a using block; using (SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection()){ connection2.Open(); ... } And remove connection2.Close();

Comment: you mean i use one connection for all  ?

Comment: You are not pulling data from different databases, right. So yes, one connection for all. And I would change the if statement to a while statement. So, instead of if (reader.Read()) {..} while (reader.Read()){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Edit

The problem is you are trying to use the same `SqlConnection` instance in 2 places. You should be using a new `SqlConnection` every time you need one.

- Create it
- Use it
- Dispose it

Code change:

```
///connection class 
public class DBConnection
{
    public static SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        String connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"];
        return new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    }
}
```

Sql Server has something called Connection Pooling and this is enabled by default. Creating a connection in c# reuses the already available connections on Sql Server so this act is very cheap. Wrap all the code that uses the `SqlConnections` in `using` blocks to ensure that they are always closed so you do not have a connection leak.

Also the app.config / web.config has a [ConnectionString section](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.85).aspx). You should use that instead of the app settings.

---

## using SqlConnection

You should wrap all your `SqlConnection` instances in `using` blocks. This will ensure that the connection is always closed and released even if exceptions occur. It takes all the checking work out of your code too, no need to see if it was opened or not at close time.

Here is your code changed with the `using` blocks, I removed some of your logic so it is clear what I had changed.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    /* your existing code removed for clarit */

    // wrapped in a using block, connection will now always be closed and disposed
    using(SqlConnection connection1 = DBConnection.getConnection())
    {
        connection1.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
        cmd1.Connection = connection1;
        cmd1.CommandText = strquery1;
        string cis = Session["customerID"].ToString();
        lbl2_customerid.Text = cis;

        SqlDataReader reader = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            /* your existing code removed for clarit */

            // wrapped in a using block, connection will now always be closed and disposed
            using(SqlConnection connection2 = DBConnection.getConnection())
            {
                connection2.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand();
                cmd2.Connection = connection2;
                cmd2.CommandText = strquery2;
                SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader2.Read())
                {
                    /* your existing code removed for clarit */
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i test with this codes and i have that error . i test with step by step debuging  and when i  got to  connection2.Open(); the error was shown

Comment: @meysam - What does `DBConnection.getConnection` do? Can you provide that code? If it returns a static connection instance (ie. the same instance) every time then that is the problem as you would by trying to change the state of the already open connection.